# How to use two fields in custom validation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation

Can someone help me get single value from `$validator->getData()`? I want to use the time and title in my query but it seems I can't get the value of time.

Here's the rule:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'name'  => 'required|min:5|max:15',
    'title' => 'required|min:5|max:100|availablee',
    'time'  => 'required|available|duration'
]);
```

This is the code for `availablee`, I can get the value of title through `$value` but I can't get the value of time from `array_get`.

```
<?php

Validator::extend('availablee', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
    $time1 = array_get($validator->getData(), $parameters[4]);
    $time = explode(" - ", $time1);

    $start = $this->change_date_format($time[0]);
    $end = $this->change_date_format($time[1]);

    // Search for any possible clash with available events
    $scene1 = DB::table('events')
        ->where('title', '==', $value)
        ->where('start_time', '<=', $start)
        ->where('end_time', '>=', $end)
        ->count();

    if ($scene1 > 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
});
```

This code gives me...

> ErrorException in CheckRoomAvailability.php line 83: Undefined offset:
>   4

Comment: well the key `4` doesnt exist in your `$parameters` variable, `dd($parameters);` above that and check its values.

Comment: i tried dd($parameters); and it gives me [ ] array. i tried to dd($validator); and it gives me the data that i need to use. how can i get the specific value on the validator? please help

Answer (score 0):

done by using this code

```
$time1 = $validator->getData();     
$time = explode(" - ",$time1['time'] );
```

instead of

```
    $time1 = array_get($validator->getData(), $parameters[4]); 
    $time = explode(" - ",$time1 );
```